# Outlook 2007 won't open calendar: "the object cannot be found"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am getting an error every time I try to edit a calendar post in Outlook 2007:

> The object cannot be found.

I've tried to create a new profile and delete the frmcache but this has not worked. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is this a calendar entry on a PST or an OST? If PST have you tried removing the data file and reimporting it?

Comment: its an ost cannt find any pst

Comment: Go to file>data file management see if there are any archived folders in there. If not you may need to talk to your IT dept, I have seen this issue with PST's and it's usually because they are larger than 2GB and need to be broken into seperate files.

Comment: sorry i forgot to say its an exchange server so there is no pst

Comment: ok i can edit stuff if owa which makes me thing it is not to do with permissions any ideas?

Comment: Delete your OST file if it's working in OWA. Go to data file management again and click open file over mailbox- your name, it should take you to a folder with a file called outlook.ost in it. Delete this file close outlook and reopen it, outlook will redownload the OST file from you exchange server which should be a good copy since it works on OWA.

Comment: O and you can still have PST if it is an Exchange setup... how do you think you archive emails? Most email servers don't have unlimited space. At my company we give our users 2 Gigs and anything over that needs to be archived into PST's.

Comment: Agree with Kyle, delete and rebuild your OST file.